# Need To Create this Image view with this border

Tags: android, imageview

Hi i need to make this image view with this border

Its polygonal image view with this border :

[image: Its polygonal image view with this border]

I have created this type of image view with this custom hexagonal masked image view .

```
public class HexagonMaskView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
private Path hexagonPath;
private Path hexagonBorderPath;
private Paint mBorderPaint,mEdgesPaint;
float radiusX;

public HexagonMaskView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public HexagonMaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public HexagonMaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    this.hexagonPath = new Path();
    this.hexagonBorderPath = new Path();

    this.mBorderPaint = new Paint();
    this.mBorderPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    this.mBorderPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    this.mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(40f);
    this.mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    this.mEdgesPaint = new Paint();
    this.mEdgesPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    this.mEdgesPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    this.mEdgesPaint.setStrokeWidth(15f);
    this.mEdgesPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

private void calculatePath(float radius) {
    radiusX = radius;

    mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(radius/3);
    mEdgesPaint.setStrokeWidth(radius/6);

    float halfRadius = radius / 2f;
    float triangleHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3.0) * halfRadius);
    float centerX = getMeasuredWidth() / 2f;
    float centerY = getMeasuredHeight() / 2f;

    this.hexagonPath.reset();
    this.hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);
    this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY + halfRadius);
    this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY - halfRadius);
    this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radius);
    this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY - halfRadius);
    this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY + halfRadius);
    this.hexagonPath.close();

    float radiusBorder = radius - 5f;
    float halfRadiusBorder = radiusBorder / 2f;
    float triangleBorderHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3.0) * halfRadiusBorder);

    this.hexagonBorderPath.reset();
    this.hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);
    this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY + halfRadiusBorder);
    this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY - halfRadiusBorder);
    this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radiusBorder);
    this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY - halfRadiusBorder);
    this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY + halfRadiusBorder);
    this.hexagonBorderPath.close();

    invalidate();
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {

    float halfRadiusBorder = radiusX / 2f;
    float radiusBorder = radiusX - 5f;
    float triangleBorderHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3.0) * halfRadiusBorder);
    float centerX = getMeasuredWidth() / 2f;
    float centerY = getMeasuredHeight() / 2f;

    c.clipPath(hexagonPath, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
    c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    super.onDraw(c);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    calculatePath(Math.min(width / 2f, height / 2f) - 10f);
}
```

this code makes a custom image view which shape is exactly as what i want but the problem is that i am not able to apply the border properly as with screen size changes the border if applied as an image overlay has issues with size as it is not applied directly on the image view

this is how i am using relative layout to make what i want

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameCont"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.dev.mytechnology.hellostream.Helper.HexagonMaskView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_43sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_43sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sample_face_1_dummy"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/frame"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_45sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/hs_hexa_frame_white" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the resulting ui produced :

[image: This is the resulting ui produced]

I know i am not using the most optimal way but please let me know how can i apply border like this on my hexagonal image view or any other option will also be appreciated.

Comment: you have to create custom layouts for each screen size

Comment: is there any other way around because this will cause a lot of trouble with different screen sizes even if i make custom layouts for each screen